# Truncate all tables and reset autoincrement

Tags: oracle, truncate

Need to prepare all tables  in Oracle database for production environment and need to truncate all tables, and reset autoincrement for columns. How can i do this?

Comment: Auto increment column? Are you talking about identity column?

Comment: Yes about identity

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do -

Run the following to generate truncate statements.  Note that it does not truncate the tables

```
select ' truncate table  ' || table_name || ';' from user_tables;
```

Review the script and ensure this is what I want.  I will then run the script.

Do similar thing for the sequences by generating the statements first as follows:

```
--Reset regular sequences.
--(Ignore identity sequences to avoid "ORA-32793: cannot alter a system-generated sequence".)
select 'alter sequence ' || sequence_name || ' restart start with 1;' v_sql
from user_sequences
where sequence_name not in (select sequence_name from user_tab_identity_cols)
order by 1;

--Reset sequences used in identity columns.
select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' modify ' ||
    '(' || column_name || ' generated by default on null as identity start with 1);' v_sql
from user_tab_identity_cols
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thank's i will try